# Compute mean value of slice of a multi-dimensional array C#

Tags: c#, recursion, multidimensional-array

I want to calculate the mean value of slices of multi-dimensional array.
The number of dimension of the array is not known before hand. The function should recursively reduce the size to reach out to the 1D base case where it calculates the mean value. For example, for a 4D incoming matrix `X`, the output is a 3D matrix whose each element represents the mean values of `X[:, i, j, k]`. For a 2D incoming matrix `X`, the output is a one-dimensional array whose element `i` is the mean value of `X[:, i]`.

Here is my C# version up to 4D which is very ugly.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace RecursiveVals3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int rndSeed = 1358;
            int[] dimVec = new int[] { 6};
            int nSim = dimVec.Aggregate(1, (acc, val) => acc * val);
            double[] x = GenRandVec(rndSeed, nSim);
            Array xMat = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(double), dimVec);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(x, 0, xMat, 0, x.Length * sizeof(double));
            var a = CalcMean(xMat);
        }

        public static double[] GenRandVec(int rndSeed, int nSim)
        {
            double[] res = new double[nSim];
            Random fixRnd = new Random(rndSeed);
            for (int i = 0; i < nSim; i++)
            {
                res[i] = fixRnd.NextDouble();
            }
            return res;
        }

        public static Array CalcMean(Array xMat)
        {
            switch (xMat.Rank)
            {
                case 1:
                    return getAve1D(xMat);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    return getAve2D(xMat);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    return getAve3D(xMat);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    return getAve4D(xMat);
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new Exception("Out of range");

            }
        }


        public static int[] reducedMatSize(int[] dim)
        {
            int[] res = new int[dim.Length - 1];
            for (int i = 0; i < dim.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                res[i] = dim[i + 1];
            }
            return res;
        }

        public static int[] getSize(Array array)
        {
            int[] dim = new int[array.Rank];
            for (int i = 0; i < dim.Length; i++)
            {
                dim[i] = array.GetLength(i);
            }
            return dim;
        }

        public static Array getAve1D(Array array)
        {
            double sum = 0.0;
            int len = array.GetLength(0);
            var res = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(double), 1);

            for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                sum += (double)array.GetValue(i);
            }
            res.SetValue(sum / len, 0);
            return res;
        }

        public static Array getAve2D(Array array)
        {
            int len = array.GetLength(0);
            var res = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(double), reducedMatSize(getSize(array)));
            for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                double sum = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
                {
                    sum += (double)array.GetValue(i, j);
                }
                res.SetValue(sum / len, j);
            }
            return res;
        }

        public static Array getAve3D(Array array)
        {
            int len = array.GetLength(0);
            var res = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(double), reducedMatSize(getSize(array)));
            for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < array.GetLength(2); k++)
                {
                    double sum = 0.0;
                    for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
                    {
                        sum += (double)array.GetValue(i, j, k);
                    }
                    res.SetValue(sum / len, j, k);
                }
            }
            return res;
        }

        public static Array getAve4D(Array array)
        {
            int len = array.GetLength(0);
            var res = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(double), reducedMatSize(getSize(array)));
            for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < array.GetLength(2); k++)
                {
                    for (int l = 0; l < array.GetLength(3); l++)
                    {
                        double sum = 0.0;
                        for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
                        {
                            sum += (double)array.GetValue(i, j, k, l);
                        }
                        res.SetValue(sum / len, j, k, l);
                    }
                }
            }
            return res;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description, but that doesn't tell us what _problem_ you're having. What have you tried, and what troubles did you encounter? Please [edit] your post to include a [valid question](/help/how-to-ask) that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know what is [on-topic](/help/on-topic); asking us to write the program for you, opinions, and external links are off-topic.

Comment: I have added my C# code here.

Comment: Use the same idea you use to generate `GenRandVec` but backwards using the `GetValue` overload that takes an `int[]` of indexes.

Comment: Where is the recursion in your sample code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By generating a value that represents the decimal equivalent of a rank-1 digit number base (each dimension length) (skipping the first dimension) you can convert that position into a slice of the array, then iterate over the first dimension for that slice:

```
Array CalcMean(Array src) {
    var rank = src.Rank;
    var lens = Enumerable.Range(0, rank).Select(d => src.GetLength(d)).ToList();
    var lenExcl0 = lens.Skip(1).DefaultIfEmpty(1).Aggregate((acc, len) => acc * len);

    var res = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(double), lens.Skip(1).DefaultIfEmpty(1).ToArray());

    var srcIndex = new int[rank];
    var resIndex = new int[rank-1];
    for (int pos = 0; pos < lenExcl0; ++pos) {
        var rmndr = pos;
        for (int dim = rank-1; dim > 0; --dim) {
            var digit = rmndr % lens[dim];
            srcIndex[dim] = digit;
            resIndex[dim-1] = digit;
            rmndr /= lens[dim];
        }

        var len0 = lens[0];
        double sum = 0;
        for (int dim0 = 0; dim0 < len0; ++dim0) {
            srcIndex[0] = dim0;
            sum += (double)src.GetValue(srcIndex);
        }
        res.SetValue(sum / len0, resIndex);
    }

    return res;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much @NetMage. This definitely works. However I am looking for a recursive version.

Comment: @user129994 Why? That would just be slower and use more stack.